# Why the result of Random Forest Algorithm change a lot when all the parameters are kept the same?

Tags: random-forest

I want to do some classification of some dataset with random forest. When I run the same script twice, two totally different(almost 5%) result were given by the program. I want to know whether random forest always give the result that change a lot with the same parameters? How can I make it more stable?

Answer (score 1):

The [Random Forest algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) involves *a lot* of randomization, as I assume you know (right?). So you will get somewhat different results each time you run it.

To obtain reproducible results, which is a good idea, initialize your random number generator with a fixed number. In R, you can do this with `set.seed(1)`, or with whatever other seed you want.

Be sure to investigate the effects of changing this seed, i.e., how sensitive your results are to your specific random number stream.

Comment: I used to think that the random can be stabled when a lot of data were feed in to the algorithm, can this be done with a lot of data and proper parameters?

Comment: It really depends on your very specific data and its relationship to the outcome variable. If two appreciably different models explain your data about equally well, then any randomization approach will frequently switch between the two models, and the end result may depend in an unstable way on which model was picked how often.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when running the Random Forest code. I wonder if this problem is already solved or not, but I found this source of the latest sklearn's glossary of Random Forest ([https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#:~:text=value%20may%20be%3A-,None%20(default),-Use%20the%20global](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#:%7E:text=value%20may%20be%3A-,None%20(default),-Use%20the%20global)).

Based on the source, we should set the "random_state" parameter (0 or 42)in order to make the model reproducible. Otherwise, the random_state will be set as None and the output models will always be different.